# What are the nuances around the different Japanese words for 'mountain' - specifically '丸'

Tags: meaning, nuances

The names of the mountains surrounding 檜原村 in western Tokyo are varied.
Examples include 三頭山, 練行峰, and 醍醐丸. Further afield, there are famous mountains like 八ヶ岳.

I have found some explanations for the differences between the suffixes 山, 岳, and 峰 in [this site](https://business-textbooks.com/yama-gaku-mine/), but would like to understand the nuance for 丸 as an indication of 'mountain.'

Answer (score 1):

The suffix 峰（みね、ほう） is supposedly for "peaks", 山（やま、さん） is supposedly for "mountains", but the actual usage is kind of mixed. I'm not sure if there is a good explanation beyond X is common and Y is uncommon. The distinction can be blurry partly because whether to call a geological feature an independent mountain or a peak that is part of a larger mountain is kind of arbitrary. (I'm sure scientists have a clear definition, but many names have been used for a long time since before the definition.)

| suffix | mountains | peaks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -峰（みね、ほう） | common | common |
| -山（やま、さん、ざん） | common | rare |
| -岳（たけ、だけ） | common | common |
| -丸（まる） | rare | uncommon |